# How to Load images from a URL into a UITableViewCell's UIImageView?

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview

Trying to fetch image from JSON and display on tableview cell but while converting to data it becomes nill

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
    NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://myurl/mypic.jpg"]];
    if ( data == nil )
        return;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // WARNING: is the cell still using the same data by this point??
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];
    });
});
```

for NSData *data its always showing nil even if i hardcode like

```
  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6b/American_Beaver.jpg/220px-American_Beaver.jpg"]];
```

it is showing nil in data variable

Is i am doing anything wrong? any other best way for same?

Comment: did you try with this url http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6b/American_Beaver.jpg/220px-American_Beaver.jpg?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) to do a lazy loading for image.

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>

[cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:IMAGE_URL]
             placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is working, You may got wrong image URL from json.

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
            NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6b/American_Beaver.jpg/220px-American_Beaver.jpg"]];
            if ( data == nil )
                return;
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // WARNING: is the cell still using the same data by this point??
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                NSLog(@"%@",image);

            });
        });
```

Comment: URL is correct just by mistake i put two diff URL in question

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h"

[cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/flower-png-22.png"]
         placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

[You can download class of SDWebImage from this link](https://github.com/ikesyo/SDWebImage)